# Select multiple ids using hstore and ActiveRecord [rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hstore

I am a little new to hstore and I'm getting stuck with the query syntax.

I'd like to find all objects with an array of foreign keys by passing in an array.

This query looks like this when using a traditional field:

```
Product.where(category_id: [1, 2, 3])
```

Is this possible to do if the category_id is in an hstore property type?